# Code Igniter Insert PHP script in my HTML View Causing Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my code :

```
<li>
    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('MainControl/adminDeportasi'); ?>">Deportasi</a>
</li>
```

I want to make link to another page using  tag in navbar list, but when I insert php script to call a controller inside the html causing next script wont read/not running. It works on my another project, but IDK how it causing error in this project.

Comment: what error u got pls specify?

Comment: try with `site_url()` instead of `base_url()` if u not remove index page using .htaccess

Comment: compile only show until before <a href> tag only, idk why, but when I only write echo 'comment' without base_url, it run completely

Comment: make sure u loaded `url` helper in `autoload.php` or in `controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Note : make sure u loaded `url` helper in `autoload.php` or in your `controller` like this *

```
$autoload['helper']  = array('url');
```

Try with `site_url()` instead of `base_url()` if u not remove index page using .htaccess

```
<li>
  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
  <a href="<?=site_url('MainControl/adminDeportasi'); ?>">Deportasi</a>
</li>
```

Comment: it works, I forget with this one, "helper". Thanks pradeep

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing This Way It Should Work

```
<li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></i><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>MainControl/adminDeportasi">Deportasi</a></li>
```